# How create a URL to device store on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite, file-manager

I'm using a SQLite to store data on my application. To view my data I need access the simulator store and execute the querys. The path to my simulators change every time that I install the app on iOS simulator. 
for example a path is:

`/Users/augustosansoncadini/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/56B6ED1A-8B79-4D5C-836D-D813EEA9FE2F/data/Containers/Data/Application/E7A7BCBD-53FE-4C84-8685-7EA1896694FF/Documents`

When I create the SQLite context, I put in this path:

`static let fileUrl = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true).appendingPathComponent("Database.sqlite3")`

So, Database.sqlite3 is stored on the documents folder of application folder. But the name of app change when I reinstall app.

Like I need access often this file, I created a Alias to navigate to this folder, but the Alias not works because the code of the app changes, so I wants to create a database file in the Store of iOS simulator but I don't know what path I must put in this line:

`static let fileUrl = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true).appendingPathComponent("Database.sqlite3")`

Answer (score 0):

By "I reinstall app." you mean that you delete from the simulator device and then install it again? or you mean when you re-run the app?

If it's the second one then you will never find your database since you deleted it along with the app.

Comment: Here is the question, I need save files in iOS`s folder, not in app folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really need is a SQLite editor that can handle file path changes automatically, so you needn't have to worry about what the path actually changes to, right?

If the answer is yes, then give [SQLiteFlow](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sqliteflow-sqlite-editor/id1378587993?mt=12) a try, it's available on App Store, and from it's documentation, it says:

> Handle database file name or directory changes. This makes SQLiteFlow can work friendly with your SQLite database in iOS simulator.