# Where is the location of the sqlite file in IOS 12?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, ios12

I am unable to locate the sqlite file for the IOS simulator. I need the file in order to inspect the data in the database for debugging.

Previously I would use:

```
NSLog(@"Documents Directory: %@", [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);
```

to get the file's location then paste it into Finder.
Now it gives me:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7DA7CB97-948B-41C6-BFA3-A50E6FF4C8B3/Documents/
```

Apple seems to have changed the file's location recently.

Answer (score 1):

**iOS .sqlite file location**

Add next arguments into Scheme

```
-com.apple.CoreData.Logging.stderr 1
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1
```

After that you will be able to find location to the file

For example:

```
CoreData: annotation: Connecting to sqlite database file at "/Users/User/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DBF9B9A0-ED0C-45E9-BEE0-CA24BE1834D3/data/Containers/Data/Application/7F285D7A-5B39-4D1C-BE48-36AC16F069CD/Library/Storage.sqlite"
```

Please note that there are can be several .sqlite files. Find yours by name

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to the *Core Data* SQLite file.

I don't think there Apple has made any changes to the file locations recently.

By default, if your app is a Core Data *document-based* app (using `UIManagedDocument`), which is rare, document files I think go into the `Documents` subfolder of your app's *Container* (sandbox).  But if your app is a Core Data *non-document-based* app, which is very common, then the single SQLite file goes into the `Application Support` subfolder of your app's *Container* (sandbox).

The NSLog() call in your question looks only for the `Documents` subfolder.  If your app is not document-based, change the constant to `NSDocumentDirectory` to `NSApplicationSupportDirectory`.  Then look in the path that it prints.

For example, in my Core Data non-document-based app, running in the iOS 12 simulator, logging the path to the Application Support Folder prints:

```
/Users/jk/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BB85B11A-5C2C-4CBC-AB4F-891C74E6FD3A/data/Containers/Data/Application/A973B1C6-4E71-43DD-8F21-6A55903E071B/Library/Application Support
```

Comment: I tried you suggestion and it returned the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found where it is.

-User->userName->Right click show Library folder

-run console command: xcrun simctl list

This will show you the ID for the Simulator you are using.

-Navigate to /Users/jk/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ and select the simulator file that matches the ID you found.

-In the finder search, search for The current Model Version name.

The end result for me was:
Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨Users⁩ ▸ ⁨userName ▸ ⁨Library⁩ ▸ ⁨Developer⁩ ▸ ⁨CoreSimulator⁩ ▸ ⁨Devices⁩ ▸ ⁨217E2EB2-139F-4568-B1D0-A6B9EE701198⁩ ▸ ⁨data⁩ ▸ ⁨Containers⁩ ▸ ⁨Data⁩ ▸ ⁨Application⁩ ▸ ⁨C69F7670-3589-4F17-BEB0-79E290206676⁩ ▸ ⁨Library⁩ ▸ ⁨Application Support⁩ ▸ AppName -> Core Data version name.

Answer (score 0):

Will this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53746942/9765789) could give you some help?

> I think what you really need is a SQLite editor that can handle file
>   path changes automatically, so you needn't have to worry about what
>   the path actually changes to, right?
>
> If the answer is yes, then give [SQLiteFlow](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sqliteflow-sqlite-editor/id1378587993?mt=12) a try, it's available on
>   App Store, and from it's documentation, it says:
>
> > Handle database file name or directory changes. This makes SQLiteFlow can work friendly with your SQLite database in iOS
> >     simulator.